# How to fix: cannot install minitube-ubuntu after full update / upgrade to 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, vlc, minitube

GENESIS

I cannot install `minitube-ubuntu` on my `14.04` Ubuntu x64 machine. Was working on `12.04` for sure. I don't remember if it broke on `upgrade` to 14.04 or later on related packages upgrade. Older `minitube` works fine, but up-to-date supported version which is `minitube-ubuntu`, does not.

---

TO THE POINT

I got a track of errors on minitube-ubuntu install, those come to `phonon-backend-vlc` as a required package, but that one eventually wants `libvlccore7 : Wymaga: vlc-data (= 2.1.5+ppa1) ale 2.2.0+ppa2.1 ma zostać zainstalowany`. Why later version of `vlc-data` does not pass validation...? Isn't that a bug?

I am currently using `phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0` and `phonon-backend-gstreamer` instead - for older `minitube`.

---

I HAVE TRIED

1. degrading `vlc-data` version and all cascade of the packages versions, but as I remember something still was not working so upgraded to latest again...
2. installing `phonon-backend-gstreamer` which should be replacement of vlc one, same error though as `gstreamer` could not be accepted.

Comment: Are you using a PPA for VLC? The `libvlccore7` package in Ubuntu Trusty depends on either `vlc-data (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1)` (if you have `trusty-updates` enabled) or `vlc-data (= 2.1.2-2build2)`.

Comment: If you want to mark your question as "answered", you should accept the correct answer (rather than editing the question).

Comment: Yeah I will as soon as I will be able to. I have to wait 2 days to accept my answer. Other guy in other question said in that case I should edit subject as answered so... whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I've disabled PPA `http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu`, the `minitube-ubuntu` could be installed.